# How can I write a test that uses a custom JPA repository without using @SpringBootTest

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa

I have written a multi-module gradle project in which:

1. App is a SpringBootApplication.
2. DataLayer contains JPA repositories and entities
3. BusinessLayer contains some business logic.

App depends on DataLayer and BusinessLayer.
There are no other dependencies between these three.

Some of the JPA repositories are customized (for instance with non trivial @Query annotations) and I would like to test them against the in memory H2 database.

I would like to write the tests in DataLayer/src/test/java and not in BusinessLayer/src/test/java and therefore I would like them to run without the `@SpringBootTest` annotation.

I have tried the following annotations on the test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {MyConfiguration.class})
```

Where MyConfiguration is annotated as follows:

```
@TestConfiguration
@ComponentScan("DataLayer")
```

And yet, Spring is unable to inject the instance of the repository into the test class.

In other tests in which I have needed to autowire concrete implementations of certain beans I have provided factory methods in MyConfiguration and annotated them with `@Bean`.
This has allowed Spring to create those beans and inject them into the test.

The problem in this case is that the custom JPA repositories are defined as interfaces in DataLayer - not concrete classes. Therefore I cannot provide factory functions in `MyConfiguration` to create them.

I have tried replacing `@SpringBootTest` with `@DataJpaTest` in order to enable auto wiring of the repositories but this also seems to bring in too many classes into my application context.

Is it possible to create concrete instances of the custom JPA Repository in code so that I might return them from `@Bean` methods in my `@TestConfiguration` class?

Alternatively, if that goes against the grain of the Spring framework, what is the recommended way to configure such a test in a way that loads as few classes as possible into the application context and yet allows Spring to autowire custom JPA repositories into the test?

Comment: "*Alternatively, if that goes against the grain of the Spring framework, what is the recommended way to configure such a test in a way that loads as few classes as possible into the application context and yet allows Spring to autowire custom JPA repositories into the test?*" - [`@DataJpaTest`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/DataJpaTest.html)

Comment: @Turing85 Thanks. I tried this and have got: "Unable to find a SpringBootConfiguration, you need to use ContextConfiguration or SpringBootTest(classes=...)".
What could be the reason?

Comment: So I replaced the @TestConfiguration annotation with SpringBootConfiguration (which I am not happy with because it is a SpringBoot component) and then saw "Unable to retrieve EnableAutoConfiguration base packages"

Comment: So I added the annotation EnableAutoConfiguration (with no arguments) on the MyConfiguration class and then got: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'repository'. So even with DataJpaTest this is not working.
Any ideas?

Comment: It seems to be working now - after I removed the annotation: @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class) from the Test class.

Comment: I was about to mark this as an answer to my question, but it actually fails. When the test class is annotated as DataJpaTest - or even as SpringBootTest but they are in a different module to the JPA repositories, the types of those repositories are not found when the application context is loaded and the test fails.

Comment: You stated above that you wanted to write tests in your DataLayer module. Now you claim your test is in a different module. Please move your test to the module it belongs to (normally, tests even reside in the same package as the uut, but in a separate `test` source set). As an aside: you cannot accept comments as an answer.

Comment: You are right, in the question I stated that I need the tests to be the DataLayer module. But I also need JPA repositories to be injected into other tests - in the BusinessLayer. 
These other tests do not test the JPAs, but they do use them. The JPAs are used in an integration test in BusinessLayer. This is what I found to be failing.

Comment: If you write an integration test, you should test the whole integration (i.e. be as close as possible to production settings). I would recommend to deploy the whole application and then use a integration testing framework to test your application. Also, please refrain from asking more than one question per post.

Comment: It should be possible to test any subset of the project as I like. I find that Spring Boot is extremely rigid - and therefore fragile - in this regard. In order to address my second question I posted it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59383157/springboottests-fail-to-autowire-custom-jpa-repositories-if-they-are-not-in-the.
I did find a solution for my second problem, which I will post there soon. 
It works but it is unintuitive and fragile. But I would no longer surprised if it is the only way that Spring Boot offers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually tried a lot of options. I was able to achieve what I needed eventually but the solution surprised me.

The source of the problem seemed to be that the `DataJpaTest` that I had written did not reside in the same package, or a parent package of the JPA repository interfaces.

Therefore the bubbling up search for types to inject never encountered them.

The solution was to create an empty class annotated with `SpringBootConfiguration` within my project but in a package named `datalayer`.

Though I had no need for such a package in the project I was writing, and this was in fact the only class ever placed in this package in this project, it was the existence of this class that enabled Spring to discover the JPA repositories that are defined in the package `datalayer.repositories`.

Comment: Were your JPA classes originally in the `datalayer.repositories` package, i.e. `DataLayer/src/test/java/datalayer/repositories`?

Comment: Hi @Christian yes, they were. I did not move them.